# Route prefix return 404

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to create an url semantic structure for a multi language site, so in the `routes.php` file I wrote all the routes in a group like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale?}', 'middleware' => ['web', 'locale', 'theme', 'currency']], function ($locale) {
    
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->defaults('_config', [
        'view' => 'shop::home.index'
    ])->name('shop.home.index');
    
});
```

the behavior of this is kinda weird, infact when I browse the site using this url: `example.com` (so without the locale prefix), everything working as expected. If instead, I add the locale prefix: `example.com/it`, I get 404, infact the `index` method of `HomeController` is never invoked.

Essentially I want that if you visit the site without prefix, then you will see the default language (en). But if you visit the site using a prefix, then, Laravel should load the locale specified as prefix.

Comment: Can you post your `php artisan route:list` output?

Comment: The behavior you're experiencing is due to the optional parameter {locale?} in the prefix of your route group. When you access the URL without a prefix, Laravel treats it as if the prefix parameter is not present, and the route is matched successfully.

Comment: However, when you access a URL with a prefix, Laravel tries to match the prefix to the {locale} parameter, and since the parameter is optional, it can be null, which is not a valid locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, you can make the {locale} parameter required by removing the question mark (?) from the prefix definition. This way, Laravel will always expect a non-empty prefix and will match the route group correctly.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}', 'middleware' => ['web', 'locale', 'theme', 'currency']], function ($locale) {
    
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->defaults('_config', [
        'view' => 'shop::home.index'
    ])->name('shop.home.index');
    
});
```